# AIML 2.0 with Python

Tags: python, chatbot, aiml

I installed AIML for python from [here](https://pypi.org/project/python-aiml/). But it had very restricted features with many tags not working. Also, it just had AIML 1.0

I tried searching for AIML 2.0 for python, but I couldn't find anywhere. The most popular repo related to this is : [Prog Y](https://github.com/keiffster/program-y). But here also, he has created few chatbots and when I tried installing the program-y bot, it gave me errors. A brief discussion I had related to this is [here](https://github.com/keiffster/program-y/issues/168#issuecomment-419414288).

So, right now I am looking for anywhere where I can install AIML 2.0 in python and create my own bots.